# how to assign string input as list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

User is giving list as input `[1,2,3,4]`:

```
a = input()
```

It is taking this as str.
I want to get this data into local list `b`.

```
b = a.strip('][').split(', ')
print(b)
```

Output: `['1,2,3,4']`

How to get list individually not a single entity?

Comment: Why did you split on a different delimiter than what the numbers are actually delimited by?

Comment: If you split everything after the first ' and before the second, you can then split on , to get each element individually. Something like sorted = a.split("'")[1].split("'")[0].split(",").

Comment: `list(map(str,a))`?  --> `['1', '2', '3', '4']`

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken If `a` is `'[1,2,3,4]'` that will give `['[', '1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ',', '4', ']']`.

Comment: then something more like `b = list(map(str,ast.literal_eval(a)))`

Answer (score 0):

You should do `.split(',')` instead of `.split(', ')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to do so.

```
import ast

a = input()
b = ast.literal_eval(a)

print(b)

# output
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

From the docs:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
> literal or container display. The string or node provided may only
> consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes,
> numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, None and Ellipsis.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
> values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
> oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex
> expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that in the line:

```
b = a.strip('][').split(', ')
```

you used ', ' **with whitespace** instead of ',' **without whitespace**
because your input does not have any spaces as shown below:

```
user is giving list as input [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`ast.literal_eval(a)` gets the string input as a `list` datatype, which can be converted into a list of individual strings with `map`:

```
import ast
b = list(map(str,ast.literal_eval(a)))
```

`['1', '2', '3', '4']`